# dynamically defined class not visible in importing module python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

A temporary exception class is defined dynamically using 'type' in a python script meant to be used as module. When an instance of this class is caught in importing script it doesn't recognize the class.
Below is code snippet

```
# the throwing module, defines dynamically
def bad_function():
    ExceptionClass = type( "FooBar", (Exception,),
        { "__init__": lambda self, msg: Exception.__init__(self, msg) })
    raise ExceptionClass("ExceptionClass")
```

the using code

```
import libt0

try:
    libt0.bad_function()
#except libt0.FooBar as e:
#print e
except Exception as e:
    print e
    print e.__class__
```

can it be explained why libt0.FooBase is not visible to this script? observer output of last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear how you expect FooBar to exist without doing something like this

```
def bad_function():
    ExceptionClass = type( "FooBar", (Exception,),
        { "__init__": lambda self, msg: Exception.__init__(self, msg) })
    globals()['FooBar'] = ExceptionClass
    raise ExceptionClass("ExceptionClass")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I must admit, my python knowledge is quite shallow. All I have learned in python is syntax and some libraries for survival. I am mostly C/C++ guy. Help really appreciated @gnibbler.

Answer (score 2):

You created the class inside a function, so it doesn't exist as a name in the module's global namespace.  In fact, it doesn't exist at all except while `bad_function` is executing.  It's the same reason why this fails:

```
# file1.py
def good_function():
   x = 2

# file2.py
import file1
print file1.x
```

Your exception class is just a local variable inside `bad_function`.